# Unformatted input/output for Fortran

Tags: python, fortran

I'm trying to use FortranFile to get an output that I can use in my simulation code written in F95. I'm having troubles getting fortranfile to work properly. Maybe it's because I do not understand how it works. Here's my problem:

If I want to write a 1D array using FortranFile, it works fine:

```
nx = 128
bxo = np.zeros(nx, dtype=float)
bxo = something
import fortranfile as fofi
bxf=fofi.FortranFile('Fbx.dat',mode='w')
bxf.writeReals(bxo,prec='d')
bxf.close()
```

The above 1D version works like a charm. As soon as I try to do it for a 2D array, I get problems

```
nx = 128; ny = 128
bxo = np.zeros((nx,ny), dtype=float)
bxo = something
import fortranfile as fofi
bxf=fofi.FortranFile('Fbx.dat',mode='w')
bxf.writeReals(bxo,prec='d')
bxf.close()
```

When I try to do this, I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/utils/py3compat.py in execfile(fname, *where)
    173             else:
    174                 filename = fname
--> 175             __builtin__.execfile(filename, *where)

/Users/parashar/Dropbox/sandbox/test2d.py in <module>()
    130 vyf=fofi.FortranFile('Fvy.dat',mode='w')
    131 vzf=fofi.FortranFile('Fvz.dat',mode='w')
--> 132 bxf.writeReals(bxo,prec='d')
    133 byf.writeReals(byo,prec='d')
    134 bzf.writeReals(bzo,prec='d')

/Users/parashar/Dropbox/sandbox/fortranfile.py in writeReals(self, reals, prec)
    215         _fmt = self.ENDIAN + prec
    216         for r in reals:
--> 217             self.write(struct.pack(_fmt,r))
    218         self._write_check(length_bytes)
    219

error: required argument is not a float
```

Any ideas what could be going on?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like Emmet's suggestion but given that my knowledge of python is very basic, it would be a lot of effort for a short goal. I just realized that I could handle the situation in a slightly different manner.

Direct access files in Fortran do not have the unnecessary leading/trailing information that the usual unformatted fortran files do. So the simplest way to deal with unformatted data exchanged between Fortran and Python is to treat the files as direct access in Fortran. Here is an example of how we can use data to/from python/fortran.

Python code:

```
import numpy as np
nx=128; ny=128;
bxo=np.zeros((nx,ny),dtype=float)
bxo=something
bxf=open('Fbx.dat',mode='wb')
np.transpose(bxo).tofile(bxf) # We transpose the array to map indices 
                              # from python to fortran properly
bxo.close()
```

Fortran code:

```
  program test
  implicit none
  double precision, dimension(128,128) :: bx
  integer :: NNN, i, j
  inquire(iolength=NNN) bx
  open(unit=23,file='Fbx.dat',form='unformatted',status='old',&
        access='direct',recl=NNN)
  read(23,rec=1) bx
  close(23)
  ! Write it out to a text file to test it
  ! by plotting in gnuplot
  do i=1,128; do j=1,128
     write(23,*) i,j,bx(i,j)
  enddo; enddo
  end
```

Because we are using the standard binary formate to read/write data, this method will work with arrays of any size unlike the FortranFile method.

I have realized that by sticking to direct access files in Fortran, we can have wider compatibility with other languages e.g. Python, IDL etc. This way we do not have to worry about the weird leading trailing markers, endian-ness etc.

I hope this will help someone else in my situation too.

Comment: Direct access files **may** not have the record markers.  There are some processors out there that still put record markers in for such files and the Fortran standard explicitly allows for this.  Use Fortran 2003's unformatted stream access instead.

Comment: Thanks for the information @IanH! I have produced direct access files on at least 5-6 different supercomputers dated from 2004-2005 to present day and have been able to read them in IDL just as plain binary files. So I was unaware of this aspect. Could you please provide some pointers to read up on this a little? Thanks!

Comment: An example of such a processor is Intel Fortran with the -vms compile flag.  Another one I've seen puts/expects a matching RECL in a header for the file for error checking.  The standard allowing for it is spread around clause 9 - look for "processor dependent"/"processor may" and you'll quickly get the idea that anything goes.  It is not by any means the common case, but the very possibility of it is why stream access was added to the language.  See F2003 or your favourite current compiler manual for a description of stream access - plenty of questions/answers discussing it on this site too.

Answer (score 0):

I've never had to do anything with Fortran and Python at the same time, and know absolutely nothing about fortranfile.py, but my best guess is that fortranfile is not numpy-aware.

When you use 1D numpy arrays, or Python arrays, lists, etc. the iteration in the last part of the stack trace suggests that it's expecting an iterable of numbers ("for r in reals"), whereas when you try to serialize a 2D numpy array, I'm not sure what it gets (i.e. what "r" ends up being), maybe an iterable of iterators, or an iterable of 1D arrays. In short, 'r' is not just the number that's expected ("required argument is not a float"), but something else (like a 1D array, list, etc.).

I would try have a look and see if there's an alternative to writeReals() in fortranfile and, if not, hack one in that can handle 2D arrays with a bit of copypasta.

I would start by putting in a diagnostic print before that "self.write()" line (217) that tells you what 'r' actually is, since it isn't the expected float.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Emmet! It would be a lot of time input for me given that I have a fairly basic understanding of python. 

I just realized that I could do things without resorting to the FortranFile package. The direct access files in fortran are practically the same as the generic unformatted binaries. So I can just write out a simple binary using numpy's tofile utility e.g. bxo.tofile('Fbx.dat') and then read Fbx.dat in fortran as a direct access file.